# How to join a map of DataFrames? Scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dictionary, join, reduce

I have a map of DataFrames:

```
val myMap = Map(
    "name1" -> df1,
    "name2" -> df2,
    "name3" -> df3
)
```

I want to join these DataFrames on a list of common columns:

```
val commonColumns = Seq("id", "time")
```

And so what statement can I write to get the effect of the below for any length of map of df's?:

```
val desiredDf = df1.join(df2, commonColumns).join(df3, commonColumns)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
val desiredDf = myMap.values.reduce((l, r) => {
  l.join(r, commonColumns)
})
```

Comment: Basically, I was very unfamiliar with reduce. This worked perfectly. Thank you!